# Generic class design for asking any type of questions with answers?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

I'm planning to design a generic class library for questionary where the user can ask any type of question (including answer to that question).
Below the design I implemented.
Can someone please take a look and suggest for any changes if any needed?

```cs
public interface IQuestion
{
    void AskQuestion();
}

public abstract class Question:IQuestion
{
    public string QuestionString { get; set; }

    public Question()
    {
        QuestionString = string.Empty;
    }

    public Question(string QuestionString)
    {
        this.QuestionString = QuestionString;
    }

    public abstract void AskQuestion();
}

public class ChoiceQuestion: Question
{
    public List<string> ChoiceList { get; set; }

    public ChoiceQuestion(string QuestionString, List<string> Choices) 
        :base(QuestionString)
    {
        ChoiceList = Choices;
    }

    public override void AskQuestion()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(QuestionString);
        foreach(string opt in ChoiceList)
        {
            Console.Write(opt + "\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n=======================================================");
    }
}

public class MultipleChoiceQuestion : ChoiceQuestion
{
    public List<string> CorrectChoices { get; set; }

    public MultipleChoiceQuestion(string QuestionString, List<string> Choices, List<string> CorrectList) 
        : base(QuestionString, Choices) 
    {
        CorrectChoices = CorrectList;
    }
}

public class OptionalChoiceQuestion : ChoiceQuestion
{
    public string Answer;

    public OptionalChoiceQuestion(string QuestionString, List<string> Choices, string CorrectChoice)
        : base(QuestionString, Choices)
    {
        Answer = CorrectChoice;
    }
}



class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Question q = new OptionalChoiceQuestion("How many rings are on the Olympic flag?", new List<string> { "None","4","5","7"}, "5");
        q.AskQuestion(); // Output to console.

        q = new MultipleChoiceQuestion("Which of these are wild animals?", new List<string> { "Tiger", "Dog", "Cat", "Elephant", "Horse" }, new List<string> { "Tiger" , "Elephant" });
        q.AskQuestion(); // Output to console.
    }
}
```

Please provide a generic design for the same.

Comment: whats wrong with this one?

Comment: I would like to know whether the design I implemented is generic or not, means will it satisfies all kinds of quesitionaries in the world, i.e., asking a basic question to multiple choice levels. Thanks.

Comment: I think it is question more suitable for [codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Appologies, I really don't know that there is another site created exclusively for resolving such queries.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing really wrong with this per se, but you should consider if you really need an Abstract class of an Interface or if you could just have a single abstract class or a single interface instead.

If you need to use IQuestion in other locations (client side for example), or will pass around implementations of IQuestion, rather than Question, then it makes sense to do this.

Of if you are allowing flexibility to expand in the future and different variations on the Interface level.

If you will only use it as shown above, in a single abstract class, that you will only create concrete instances of descendants of this Question base class, then I would suggest that you don't really need this and that you have over-engineered.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I totally agree to your point, but what I am really trying to achieve here is to implement a generic library for the same, so that I need not relying on implement a concreate class for each different question comes (who knows).